# Не пойму в чем проблема. BooleanField не имеет атрибута?

Tags: django

Всем привет. При запуске сервера выдает следующее
[image: 1]

Вот файл forms.py

```css
from django.forms import ModelForm, Form
from . import models
from . import forms
from .models import Author1
from .models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse


class AuthorOneForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author1
        fields = ['name', 'surname', 'city']

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['author', 'title', 'text']

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    boolean_field = forms.BooleanField()
    float_field = forms.FloatField()
    name_sender = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Введите ваше имя')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label = 'Сообщение')
    sender = forms.EmailField(label='Введите ваш эмейл')
```

Должно быть так ... (правда версии джанго на скрине 1,11 у меня 2,2)
[image: 2]

В документации рекомендуют использовать NullBooleanField - но меня это не спасает...
P.S (только учусь опыта мало)

Comment: Не надо в forms.py писать `from . import forms`.

Comment: Верно спасибо большое...